# How to execute python script with infinite loop from raspberry pi website by button click?

Tags: php, python, ajax, raspberry-pi

I'm making an alarm system on raspberry pi. I have a python script, which detects motion, inserts data about it into mysql database and later displays it on website from database. I don't use frameworks like flask, django. I use html, php and also javascript from bootstrap framework to do responsive website. Now I would like to do a button (ON/OFF) on website, which will control python script, which I've described above. I'd like to do this in simple way, because I'm begginer in that. Is it possible to do this with php code, maybe with js, ajax not to refresh page, but without using frameworks like flask? Currently it will be localhost, but for example is it possible to host this website and remote control python script from mobile phone with php code? I've tried to do this with php code, but it is not working.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
    exec('python /var/www/html/alarmV1.py');
}

?>

<form name="update" method="post" >                         
<input type="submit" value="Włącz" name="update" style="color:white; 
background-color: green; " >
</form>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: "it's not working" is a completely useless problem description. We already know that. The code you posted is essentially fine, that's exactly how you would run commands on your Pi from a website. Now you need to debug it, narrow down the problem. I assume the command `python /var/www/html/alarmV1.py` works when you run it from a terminal?

Comment: Yes it works from terminal and now I'd like to run from button click on website

Comment: Change python to direct path (`which python`) to find. If that doesn't work created a new page without the POST check to check if the command it self is the problem.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is if that Python script has an infinite loop, PHP will wait for it to finish, i.e. hang. What exactly is happening when you send that form?

Comment: Now, I'm edited exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/alarmV1.py') but still not working. When I click on button the page is only refreshing. The python script doesn't run.